# How to use enums?

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to use enum in Java. Am I using it right in the following example?

```
enum Sex {M, F};

public class person{  
    private person mom;  
    private Sex sex;

    public person(Sex sex){  
        this.sex = sex;  
        //is this how i'd set sex?  
    }  

    public void setMom(person mom){  
        if(mom.sex == 'M'){}  
        //is this how i would check to see if the sex of the passed person argument is male?  
   }  
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is **not** a replacement for googling "Java enum tutorial" ...

Comment: @Joachim: Wow let me guess today was code review day? :)

Comment: @Luis: there are (a lot of) questions where SO is the ideal place. General tutorials are simply not among that set.

Comment: True but tutorials are one-way street whereas SO allows a bit of communication and reformulation.

Answer (score 5):

This is what you want to use:

```
 if(mom.sex == Sex.M)
```

however, I would definitely spell out the enum constants as MALE and FEMALE.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you should simply write:

```
public void setMom(person mom){  
    if(mom.sex == Sex.M){}  
    //is this how i would check to see if the sex of the passed person argument is male?
```

}

Please note that `enums` allow you to check equality with `==`

You can have a look to http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html for more information.

Answer (score 2):

There is third possibility you might not have considered is `null`. e.g. mom.sex could be `MALE`, `FEMALE` or `null`

If you what to validate I would write it as

```
if(mom.sex != Sex.FEMALE) // not the only valid option.
```

As an enum type may get more options over time, this is best practice IMHO.

A `Person` should have a `mom` when created/born. I would add this to the constructor and possibly not allow it to be changed. i.e. make the `mom` and/or `sex` final and drop the setter.